# Solicitar una contraseña al intentar cerrar una aplicacion de python

Tags: python-3.x, ventana, contraseña

*Buenas, estoy corriendo un scipt q se ejecuta de manera cuentinua y periodica, similar al siguiente*:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

time1=dt.datetime.today()
renovar=True
while renovar==True:
    repeat=True
    while repeat==True:
        time2=dt.datetime.today()
        timedelta=time2-time1
        if timedelta.seconds==1:
            print(time2)
            time1=time2
            repeat=False
```

*Necesito que  al intentar cerrar la ventana en la cual se esa ejecutando el programa, se solicite una contraseña.
El codigo presentado es una simplificacion, pero muestra la esencia del que estoy corriendo,
desde ya agradezco vuestro tiempo y paciencia, saludos!!!*

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una variable que se llama renovar a True. Cuando sales del bucle estará a False. Por tanto pregunta por ella para pedir la contraseña. De hecho, no hace ni falta por que cuando sales del bucle es que eso mismo se ha producido y puedes pedir la contraseña.